# Create samples from the output of a combn function in R, with no repeated elements

Tags: r, unique, combn

I am trying to solve this problem with R: out of all possible combinations of letters, I want to randomly select a sample of 13 pairs with the condition that no LETTER is repeated.

I am trying the following:

```
x<- LETTERS
combi <- combn(x, 2, FUN = NULL, simplify = FALSE) #combines by 2
fulltable <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind, combi)) #Convert list to dataframe of 2 columns
```

It gives me 323 possible combinations:

```
...
X.316  V  Y
X.317  V  Z
X.318  W  X
X.319  W  Y
X.320  W  Z
X.321  X  Y
X.322  X  Z
X.323  Y  Z
```

I want to select a sample -lets call it SET1- of 13 pair of letters (there are 26 letters in total) where no letter is repeated. 
Then, once these pairs are created, I want to extract another sample with the same condition, but in this case, excluding SET1.

Desired outcome:

```
X.1  A  E
X.2  C  H
X.3  B  X
X.4  W  Y
X.5  F  K
…..
```

Until X.13 and no letter repeated either in row or column.

In the second sample extraction,again, a combination of pairs with unique letters, but in this case, previous combinations not allowed (i.e. A E / C H).
It should also exclude permutations, such as E A / H C.

Thanks
AJS

EDIT---------------------
This solution works for me:

```
test <- LETTERS
ctest <- combn(test, 2, FUN = NULL, simplify = FALSE)
ctabl <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind,ctest))
ctabl$row <- 1:nrow(ctabl)

for (i in 1:nrow(ctabl)){
  sname <- ctabl%>% sample_n(13)
  ctabl <- ctabl %>% subset(!row %in% sname$row)
  print(sname)
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! I would be helpful if you added some description of your desired output. For example, you could post an additional code panel which show what SET1 should look like. That'll make it easier for others to assist you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the output should be a dataframe with 2 columns, and each row a unique par. No letter should be repeated either in row or column. For instance: A  B /  C D / E F …. etc would be a valid outcome. For context: I am trying to randomly pair + 300 colleagues in my company for a network activity, : ). This activity will be repeated weekly, hence I need to exclude previous combinations and each colleague should be counted just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach to obtain comparable results, hope it helps...

```
> x  <- sample(LETTERS, replace = F)
>  ft <- data.frame(x[1:13],x[14:26])
>  ft
   x.1.13. x.14.26.
1        X        D
2        T        Y
3        P        N
4        Z        I
5        M        E
6        K        V
7        B        J
8        R        O
9        H        C
10       S        L
11       A        W
12       G        Q
13       U        F

> # UPDATE based on comment:  
> # That probably moves the post from primarily being R, to being a math problem 
>  # It depends if you want a comprehensive ste of solutions or a couple unique solutions
>  # Couple unique solutions is easier: 
> x1 <- x[1:13]

x1 <- x[1:13]

x2 <- x[14:26];  df2 <- data.frame(x1,x2); df2
x3 <- x[c(15:26,14)]; df3 <- data.frame(x1,x3); df3
x4 <- x[c(16:26,14:15)]; df4 <- data.frame(x1,x4); df4
x5 <- x[c(17:26,14:16)]; df5 <- data.frame(x1,x5); df5
# .... and so on till x14
# Implemented code 
> x1 <- x[1:13]
> 
> x2 <- x[14:26];  df2 <- data.frame(x1,x2); df2
   x1 x2
1   X  D
2   T  Y
3   P  N
4   Z  I
5   M  E
6   K  V
7   B  J
8   R  O
9   H  C
10  S  L
11  A  W
12  G  Q
13  U  F
> x3 <- x[c(15:26,14)]; df3 <- data.frame(x1,x3); df3
   x1 x3
1   X  Y
2   T  N
3   P  I
4   Z  E
5   M  V
6   K  J
7   B  O
8   R  C
9   H  L
10  S  W
11  A  Q
12  G  F
13  U  D
> x4 <- x[c(16:26,14:15)]; df4 <- data.frame(x1,x4); df4
   x1 x4
1   X  N
2   T  I
3   P  E
4   Z  V
5   M  J
6   K  O
7   B  C
8   R  L
9   H  W
10  S  Q
11  A  F
12  G  D
13  U  Y
> x5 <- x[c(17:26,14:16)]; df5 <- data.frame(x1,x5); df5
   x1 x5
1   X  I
2   T  E
3   P  V
4   Z  J
5   M  O
6   K  C
7   B  L
8   R  W
9   H  Q
10  S  F
11  A  D
12  G  Y
13  U  N
> # .... and so on till x14
> 
> # You may need to write a loop /nested loop to get a comprehensive set
> # logic is - find N, combinations of 2/26 letters, then find the combinations of 13/length(N) those 
> # with the condition that no character is repeated in a single vector of any combination in any df.
```

Comment: A good solution. But, how do I now extract another set with 13 pairs and none repeated from this extraction?  i.e.no X D pair and no D X pair either, no T Y or Y T. But it could be X Y, for instance, since it is a new combination.

Comment: Just updated solution with workaround for a few unique solutions but not a comprehensive set, it would be great for the SO community if you post the solution for the complete set, if you get down to writing the loops /find alternative solution.

Comment: I did find a loop solution!, combining mi initial solution, xillian suggestion and your proposal of a loop function to generate all possible combinations. I include it in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

For the additional condition just added - you could use set.seed before sample(LETTERS, replace = F) to control sequences and ensure a different ft.